# Wrong JSON object sent from PHP to Android

Tags: php, android, json

I am facing a very unusual problem. 
I am sending an http post request from android to a upOR.php file. But , the JSON response that I am getting if from another dlQues.php file!!! The file name referred in android is correct as the code written for inserting data into the file is being executed. In fact, there seems to be nothing wrong with the code of the upOR.php file. It is returning correct JSON when simply run on the browser. But it returns the JSON from dlQues.php when called from android, even though the code of upOR.php is executed !!. Also, when dlQues.php was deleted, it began returning JSON from yet another file!.

Plz help. It is baffling me.

Comment: Both. Strip it to the essentials. Likely, you'll find your mistake yourself once you start doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This will not happen, would be due to human mistakes :)

1. Check the path again, to see if they are right or wrong.
2. Echo simple text like ABCD from first file and XYZ in second, and run it from ANdroid to see it is being invoked.

Debug it step by step and it would surely be a really simple mistake!

Comment: I placed the file in another folder. Now upOR.php is the only file in the folder. I changed the path in the code too. Stil getting the json reply from the wrong file!